# concurrently linked list with locks throwing segmentation fault(core dump) every time I try to run it

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am trying to just insert into a concurrent linked list. my code always gives me a segmentation fault(core dumped) when I try to use my list_insert function and I can't figure out why. Starting with an empty list, two threads running at the same time, I am trying to insert 1 million random integers each on the same list. I have attached my code. Thank you for the help

```
// basic node structure
typedef struct __node_t {
int key;
struct __node_t *next;
} node_t;


//basic list structure (one used per list)
    typedef struct __list_t {
    node_t *head;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
} list_t;`

void List_Init(list_t *L) {
L->head == NULL;
pthread_mutex_init(&L->lock, NULL);
}

void List_Insert(list_t *L, int key) {
// synchronization not neded
node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
if (new == NULL){
    perror("malloc");
    return;
}
new->key = key;

// just lock cricical section
pthread_mutex_lock(&L->lock);
new->next = L->head;
L->head = new;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&L->lock);
}
```

Main function

```
//main function 
int main(int argc, char** argv){

// create random number
srand(time(0));

//create list
list_t *the_list;
List_Init(the_list);

struct timeval start, stop;

// start of timer
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

printf(" %d ", rand());
List_Insert(the_list, 1);

//stop timer
gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);

//get time passed
double time;

time = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1e6;
time = (time + (stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec)) * 1e-6;

printf("Time Passed: %f\n", time);

return 0;
```

Comment: `list_t *the_list;` is an uninitialized pointer. And despite its name `List_Init` does not initialize it

Comment: @R.J. Williams For almost all segmentation faults the first thing you should do is run your program under valgrind or similar. They will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @UnholySheep Okay thank the List_Init was given by the TA. how would I initialize the list?

Comment: If you really cannot change `List_Init` then you will have to do `the_list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));` before you call the function

Comment: @UnholySheep okay thank you so much. that fixed it.